# Facebook Graph API searching for a person's profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the Graph API but the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture) state that to search for a users profile picture, you do not need to include an access token in the request:

> Because profile pictures are always public on Facebook, this call does not require any access token.

No when I run: `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200`

I get the following in the response: `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Is this a bug that I can report or am I horribly misinterpreting the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want Facebook to guess who is "me"?

> `/me` is a special endpoint that translates to the user ID of the
>   person whose access token is being used to make the request.

*Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2*

An access token makes the link between a Facebook account and a graph request. So if you want to use "me", you must give an access token for Facebook to know that "me" is in fact *you*.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

---

If you want to get your profile picture without an access token, just replace `me` by your `USER_ID`:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/USER_ID
```

Comment: Good info, thanks. I guess I should try to read the quick start in future ;)

Answer (score 1):

Querying with a Facebook ID instead of "me" works. It seems that a token is required to get info about the current logged in user...

Comment: please make that a comment or edit your own question as it doesn't answer the question but just gives more information about your problem

Comment: it is actually the answer, not just a comment. not very detailed, but still... ;)

Comment: I agree, it is an answer, just not very in depth. Because of that I will accept @StéphaneBruckert answer.